# Change Adfly ads to js

Tags: javascript

Im trying to inject this to an JS file.

```
<script>
var adfly_id = 3793905;
var adfly_advert = 'banner';
var frequency_cap = 5;
var frequency_delay = 5;
var init_delay = 3;
</script>
<script src="adf.ly/js/entry.js"></script>
```

And just load it by adding this to my page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://server.com/adfly.js"></script>
```

Is it possible? because I have no luck.

I try all this...

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript">var adfly_id = 3793905;var adfly_advert = 'int';var frequency_cap = 5;var frequency_delay = 5;var init_delay = 3;</script><script src="cdn.adf.ly/js/entry.js"></script>');
```

--

```
var adfly_id = 3793905;
var adfly_advert = 'int';
var frequency_cap = 4;
var frequency_delay = 5;
var init_delay = 3;
src="cdn.adf.ly/js/entry.js"
```

AND

```
var sc = document.createElement('script');
sc.src = "adf.ly/js/entry.js"
document.body.appendChild(sc);
unsafeWindow.adfly_id = 3793905;
unsafeWindow.adfly_advert = 'int';
unsafeWindow.frequency_cap = 5;
unsafeWindow.frequency_delay = 5;
unsafeWindow.init_delay = 3;
```

And it dint work with any of this codes. can anyone help me
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're quite close on the last piece of code.

The problems there are that you don't define the script type, and you place it in the `body` instead of the `head`.

This is an adapted copy from what Google does for DFP:

```
var ads = document.createElement('script');
ads.async = true;
ads.type = 'text/javascript';
var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
ads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//adf.ly/js/entry.js';
var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
node.parentNode.insertBefore(ads, node);
```

Comment: Yes im placing the script on the body. This script will work?  Where is my adfly_id. Im learning javascript, Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: the above code will create the script tag ( `<script src="adf.ly/js/entry.js"></script>` in your first sample ). You can add the rest after that.